# How to put a PHP Variable into output of a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I am querying my DB for a file. And I want to use a PHP global variable and stick it somewhere in that output using say a '$dir' in my table. Any possible way to do so?

Comment: What do you want exactly? What is this "output"? Just a variable? You can concatenate variables.

Answer (score 1):

Just use it in a string for the query like you would in any other string. eg:

`$sql = "UPDATE TABLE x SET dir=" . $dir . " WHERE id=" . $id;`

Though if you do this and your variables use user input it's VERY IMPORTANT to sanitize them against SQL injection and such. The function `mysql_real_escape_string()` is provided for just such instances.

`$sql = "UPDATE TABLE x SET dir=" . mysql_real_escape_string($dir) . " WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($id);`

Comment: This upvote shows us the intelligence level of the usual SO participant

Answer (score 0):

$query = "SELECT '" . $dir . "' as myVariable, userName, userpassword from users where userName = ...."

Answer (score -1):

The first reply was missing some quotes:

$sql = "UPDATE TABLE x SET dir=" . $dir . " WHERE id=" . $i

->

$sql = "UPDATE TABLE x SET dir='" . mysql_real_escape_string($dir) . "' WHERE id=" . $i

and

$sql = "UPDATE TABLE x SET dir=" . mysql_real_escape_string($dir) . " WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($id);

->

$sql = "UPDATE TABLE x SET dir='" . mysql_real_escape_string($dir) . "' WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($id);

Comment: feel like quoting integer? I'd personally use intval instead of quoting/mysql_real_escape_string but everyone to its own.

Comment: i am not a telepathist. I don't know what you feel. I just see what you wrote. And there is missing quotes.